# Customize maven remote repository

Tags: maven

So my company has an internal maven repository deployed, and I'm supposed to download everything internally not from maven central repository.  I'm setting the `repositories` element like this

```xml
<project>
    <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>Internal-maven-repo</id>
          <name>Repo</name>
          <url>http://build.a.com/nexus/content/groups/repo</url>
          <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

So, when doing `maven package`, do I need to specify a repository id in `pom.xml`?  How do I know it's downloading from the internal repository but not externally?

Answer (score 1):

The  correct configuration for a `settings.xml` in relationship with a nexus [repository manager looks like this](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html):

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And it is necessary to enable snapshots as well as releases.